# How to randomize a hex value between ''00' - 'FF' in PHP

Tags: php, random, hex

So, through PHP I am trying to randomize a hex value between 00 and FF. I want to use this as a value for (example):

```
fseek($f, '0x01B6F0');
fwrite($f, pack('c', hexdec(""MY RANDOMIZED VALUE")));
```

I see some examples on my internet searches on how to randomize the location, by which I mean 0x000000 - 0xFFFFFF, but I am only interested in the value. Sorry, I don't know the lingo like 'offset' and such to clearly state what I mean, but I think I stated it well enough to get suggestions on how to do this (like '0C' or '47'... or 0x01B6F0:0C). Thanks!

Comment: Generate a random number between 0 and 255 and convert it to hex.

Comment: Hmm, that only seems to be randomizing 0x000000 - 0xFFFFFF when I use 
hexdec($r); with $r being rand(1,255).
Is there a way to just rand 00-FF, because I want to put, say "F7" into 0x000001, not 0x123456 into 0x000001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, generate a number between 0 and 255 and then use `dechex()` to convert decimal to hex (and not `hexdec()`)...

```
echo dechex(rand(1,255))
```

Comment: Ahh beautiful, thanks tkausl and Nigel! This is exactly what I am trying to do. I didn't understand what tkausl was saying at first because I didn't know that he meant to use dechex and not hexdec. Truth be told, I've never used dechex before, or knew that it was a thing. Anyway, thanks guys!